# Рекурсивный алгоритм. Переполнение стека

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

Во время выполнения моего алгоритма, много раз вызывается рекурсивный dfs, после чего я получаю

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in **instancecheck**

Такое ощущение, что происходит накопление рекурсивных вызовов за всё время работы программы. После превышения порога в сумме

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
```

программа падает. Как с этим бороться?

Я приведу псевдокод моего алгоритма:

```
func dfs(current):
    global labels
    labels[current] = true
    for neighbour in get_neighbours(current):
        if not (labels[neighbour]):
            dfs(neighbour)
        do_smth()

for item in range(0, n):
   dfs(item) // Происходит несколько итераций цикла, после чего прога падает. При увеличении значения n в sys.setrecursionlimit(n) алгоритм выполняет больше итераций в цикле, но всё равно падает.
```

Таким образом, в некоторый момент возникает вышеуказанная ошибка. Замечу, что данная ошибка возникает у меня уже не первый раз. Возникает она в любом месте, где есть достаточное количество вызовов рекурсивных алгоритмов с большой глубиной рекурсии.

Замечу, что в коде нет терминального условия, но это не означает, что код будет выполняться бесконечно. Прокомментирую. Мы рассматриваем граф G(V, E). Будем перебирать вершины, начиная с любой. Каждую вершину мы будем помечать, если мы в ней были. Это делается следующей командой:

```
labels[current] = true
```

Для каждой вершины мы перебираем всех её соседей:

```
for neighbour in get_neighbours(current):
```

Если в вершине-соседе мы были, то в неё заходить не следует. Если же нет, то перейдём в нее. Проверка были мы там или нет осуществляется так:

```
if not (labels[neighbour]):
```

Далее переходим в вершину:

```
dfs(neighbour)
```

О конкретном алгоритме можно прочесть [здесь](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/resource/view.php?id=1035). Но спешу заметить, что вопрос заключается не в алгоритме, а в принципах устройства python. Подробное описание кода я привёл лишь для того, чтобы снять сомнения в его работоспособности. Код взят лишь как пример и не более того.

Comment: что есть `рекурсивный dfs`? Имеется в виду "depth-first search" или нечто другое?

Comment: @MaxU Да, он самый. Но сути это не отменяет. Такая ситуация наблюдается для любого рекурсивного алгоритма

Comment: Попробуйте [нерекурсивный алгоритм](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278667/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU Всё это я прекрасно понимаю. Но мне непонятно, почему происходит такая беда с рекурсией.

Comment: @hedgehogues такая беда происходит потому, что алгоритм с depth-first search по определению пытается в первую очередь уйти на максимальную глубину. При достаточно большом количестве узлов 100% произойдет выход за пределы лимита максимальной глубины рекурсии.

Comment: это будет в  любом языке. краткий ответ - думайте сколько вам нужно стека заказывайте не меньше.

Comment: @pavel Почему такого не происходит на c? Почему вдруг, когда я увеличиваю максимальную глубину, алгоритм позволяет запустить несколько раз dfs? Ну, это бред. Нет у меня такого огромного количества узлов, чтобы алгоритм не уложился в 20000. НЕТУ! Для того, чтобы он вылетел, необходимо, как минимум больше 20000 вершин. Завтра, как приду на работу подсчитаю, сколько в каждой компоненте связности вершин.

Comment: Почему не происходит?)) 4 метра стека по умолчанию. А дальше смотря сколько переменных в функции. На пол миллиона вершин обычно уже не хватает. И вопрос немного неправильный тогда, вы знаете как увеличить лимит. Вон на lua около 200 вызовов по умолчанию и что? Боюсь ответ правильный - так решили создатели языка.

Comment: Для начала определите, на каком item из range у вас происходит падение и что будет, если сразу однократно вызвать функцию именно для этого item. А то, может быть, всё дело в том, что у вас где-то ошибка в коде. Вообще, хорошо бы увидеть реальный код. Никакого глобального накопления вызовов быть не должно.

Comment: Скорее всего, какая-то ошибка с тем, как реализован labels и проверка элемента в нём - это самое подозрительное место во всём вашем псевдокоде.

Comment: Если рекурсия не работает, то нужно от неё избавится. Реализуй свой стек на генераторе и обходи его for`ом

Comment: @pavel специально затестил, сколько у меня вершин. DFS работает лишь на компонентах связности. Отсюда вывод, что нам нужно вычислить макс. размер компонент связности. Размер равен 4053 вершин. Это ОЧЕНЬ немного!

Comment: @hedgehogues а можете запускаемый пример, может что-то в методике тестирования... Например вы весь массив копируете в функцию а не глобально передаёте. Я не специалист по питону, но это может помочь тем, кто разбирается.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Я протестировал на C. В итоге, ошибка повторилась. Начал разбираться с файлами. В итоге нашёл огромной кластер, который визуально был незаметен. Максимальный размер кластера 4053, действительно таковым является. Но, поскольку, на последней итерации алгоритм падал, тот самый большой кластер не обнаруживался (максимальный размер кластера не обновлялся).

Comment: @hedgehogues может, ответ напишете? Кстати, есть такая идея: если для рекурсии глубина стека слишком большая, можно вместо рекурсивного вызова добавлять задачу в очередь обработчика. У очереди глубина не увеличивается. (возможно, именно про это выше пишет eri)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ответ заключается в том, что я из-за ошибки и своей невнимательности долго не мог заметить свою ошибку. Ошибка же состояла в том, что, действительно, стек рвался из-за слишком глубокой рекурсии и слишком большого кластера.

Comment: @hedgehogues: Тогда, может быть, напишите альтернативный подход с явным списком заданий?

Comment: посмотрите пару примеров нерекурсивной реализации поиска в глубину на Питоне. [Как применить функцию ко всем элементам списка (произвольной вложенности)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608684/23044) и [Обход массива в глубину: код подсчёта количества грядок на садовом участке не проходит тесты на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591631/23044) Рассмотрите возможность готовую библиотеку использовать, если задаче не образовательная как в ответе на вопрос: [Работа с set'ами. Костыли. Имея набор попарных связей, определить связаны ли два заданных узла](https://goo.gl/o8G18M)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно на Вашу функцию

```
func dfs(current):
    global labels
    labels[current] = true
    for neighbour in get_neighbours(current):
        if not (labels[neighbour]):
            dfs(current)
        do_smth()
```

Я удалю несколько часть строк, что бы показать явную проблему

```
func dfs(current):
    #
    dfs(current)
    #
```

переменная `current` не меняется внутри функции. И получается, что значение фукнции зависит от значения функции. Такая рекурсия никогда не закончится. Именно для этого в большинстве интерпретаторов есть защита от таких бесконечных рекурсий - лучше программисту сразу намекнуть, что его код подозрительный.

Что делать? Исправить код. Как минимум, думаю нужно изменить параметр. А вот как именно - это только Вы знаете.

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил псевдокод на `dfs(neighbour)`. Но вопроса это не отменяет. Это была досадная опечатка в псевдокоде. А вопрос связан с особенностью языка python

Comment: Это не особенность этого конкретного языка. Это особенность всех языков. Рекурсивные функции всегда требуют много памяти.Тут на помощь приходят итерации

Comment: Ответ неверный, потому что кто сказал, что `get_neighbours(current)` всегда возвращает одно и тоже?

Answer (score 0):

Может вам надо переписать DFS на нерекурсивную версию? Я в алгоритмах 0 но  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508819/1717474 вот ответ на ваш вопрос по моему, а если вам надо времена входа/выхода "корректные" то все сложнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43906820/1717474

Comment: Я решил проблему

Comment: Можно прочесть комменты